# Incrementing uniqueID over each List.map iteration

Tags: elm

I'm trying to initialise a set of elements with a unique identifier. The elements are part of the initial model.

What I have in mind is a function

```
initElement: Int -> InputElement -> Output
initElement id element = ...
```

that adds the given id to the given element. Now I'm iterating over these elements in another function like this:

```
uid = 0    
elementsList = ...    
newList = List.map (initElement uid++) elementsList
```

and I would want this integer **uid** increased with every iteration over an element by List.map, so that every element gets a unique number assigned. The ++ obviously doesn't work though.

Is this possible, or am I thinking too object-oriented? I'm pretty new to functional programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use List.indexedMap

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/List#indexedMap

It gives you a nice incrementing index as a parameter to your function as first parameter. Which you can then use to modify the incoming uid approriattely